# Send splunk alert results to SNMP server using python script

Tags: python, snmp, splunk

I could see Perl script to send Splunk alert results to SNMP server. But i want to write python script which needs to send results to Snmp server.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to your splunk server also send your access,error logs with your splunk forwarder via python